# Python searching multiple directories and reading select files

Tags: python, glob, text-parsing

I am looking for some help performing actions on a set of files in two different directories using Python.

I am attempting to:

1. Search two different directories
2. Find the 15 last modified files (comparing files in both directories)
3. Read all 15 recently modified files line by line

I can accomplish reading through one file directory using glob. However, I cannot specify multiple directories. Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Below is my code which accomplishes grabbing the latest 15 files in dir1 but not dir2.

```
dir1 = glob.iglob("/dir1/data_log.*")
dir2 = glob.iglob("/dir2/message_log.*")

latest=heapq.nlargest(10, dir1, key=os.path.getmtime)
for fn in latest:
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are after but if you were to use `glob.glob` instead of `glob.iglob`, you could do

```
dir1 = glob.glob("/dir1/data_log.*")
dir2 = glob.glob("/dir2/message_log.*")

latest=heapq.nlargest(10, dir1+dir2, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

And actually, if you don't like the idea of using lists (`glob.glob`) instead of generators (`glob.iglob`), you can do

```
from itertools import chain

dir1 = glob.iglob("/dir1/data_log.*")
dir2 = glob.iglob("/dir2/message_log.*")

latest=heapq.nlargest(10, chain(dir1, dir2), key=os.path.getmtime)
```